# CiviCRM Says Cron Job Not Running But It Is

Tags: cron

The pop up message in CiviCRM says the Cron is not running, but the Admin Page states it is. CiviCRM v5.16.2 on WordPress.

[image]

Comment: It has to run once an hour or less, otherwise it thinks it isn't running

Comment: Seems to be set up for every 15 minutes although I do not know a bunch about it. Had a friend help me with it a year ago. Just stopped working when I updated from 5.13.x to 5.16.2 ... */15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u civicrm -p xxxxxxx -e Job -a execute

Comment: This back from hosting provider:  We have checked your case and would like to inform you that the Cron Job is set up properly in the Cron Jobs tool in the cPanel.

Having that in mind, we suggest you contact the plugin's vendor so they could further investigate the issue and assist you in resolving it.

Comment: Did anything change with the `civicrm` user account/permissions? Or the file permissions?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. We just updated it. The framework is on WP and we don't add much there ever.

Comment: Have you changed your admin password in WP?